# How can I show only the nested elements when I click on the parent? - React

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a navigation menu with three levels of nesting created with a json. When you click on the `Parent` it shows all the children, regardless of the parent you press.
I would like you to click on the `Parent` to show only your children and not all the children of all the parents ... I just need to make the distinction between the `Parent` and the direct `Child`, which is directly associated with the third level and is shown at the same time

I think that in addition to the conditional `this.state.showSubmenu` I have to do another one to detect the origin of the Parent, but I am not able to do it. On the other hand I think that one could make a .filter or .reduce to only show the son of the element clicked.

```
"menu":[
{   
    "fsttitle":"CRM", 
    "ico":"auriculares", 
    "fstmenu":[{
            "sndtitle":"Argumentarios",
            "ico":"descargar",      
            "sndmenu":[
                {"Id":"114","trdtitle":"SALUD NORMAL1","URL":"https:/argumentarios\/argsalud.pdf","Closable":"1","Autoload":"0","Visible":"1"},
                {"Id":"115","trdtitle":"SALUD NORMAL2","URL":"https:/argumentarios\/argsalud.pdf","Closable":"1","Autoload":"0","Visible":"1"},
                {"Id":"116","trdtitle":"SALUD NORMAL3","URL":"https:/argumentarios\/argsalud.pdf","Closable":"1","Autoload":"0","Visible":"1"}
            ]
            }]
},
{   "fsttitle":"Permisos", 
    "ico":"candado", 
    "fstmenu":[{
            "sndtitle":"Herramientas",
            "ico":"herramienta",            
            "sndmenu":[
                {"Id":"117","trdtitle":"SALUD NORMAL4","URL":"https:/argumentarios\/argsalud.pdf","Closable":"1","Autoload":"0","Visible":"1"},
                {"Id":"118","trdtitle":"SALUD NORMAL5","URL":"https:/argumentarios\/argsalud.pdf","Closable":"1","Autoload":"0","Visible":"1"},
                {"Id":"120","trdtitle":"SALUD NORMAL7","URL":"https:/argumentarios\/argsalud.pdf","Closable":"1","Autoload":"0","Visible":"1"}
            ]
            },
            {
            "sndtitle":"Leads",
            "ico":"user-lead",      
            "sndmenu":[
                {"Id":"119","trdtitle":"SALUD NORMAL6","URL":"https:/argumentarios\/argsalud.pdf","Closable":"1","Autoload":"0","Visible":"1"}
            ]
            }]
}]
```

**Edit: I fix my code and now my code works fine.** I can show the three levels in my menu.

```
class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            navigation: {
                menu: [],
            },
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http:json_menuFIN.php')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>{
                this.setState({navigation: data});                
            })
    }

    render(){
        const renderMenu = items => {
            return (
                <ul className="list">
                    {items.map((i, key) => {
                        var icoJson;
                        if(i.ico){
                            icoJson = <Icon icon={i.ico} className={"ico-" + i.ico} />;
                        }
                        const showHideSubmenu = (index, key) => {
                            this.setState({
                                showfstmenu: index,
                            });
                        }
                        var firstMenu = i.fstmenu ? "first-menu" : "";
                        var secondMenu = i.sndmenu ? "second-menu" : "";
                        var classMn = i.fstmenu ? "mn-" : "";
                        var classSb = i.sndmenu ? "sb-" : "";
                        return (
                            <li className={`list__item ${firstMenu}${secondMenu}`} key={i.fsttitle + i.sndtitle + i.trdtitle}>
                                <a 
                                    href={i.URL} 
                                    className={`${classMn}${classSb}`+i.fsttitle}
                                    onClick={(key) => i.fstmenu ? showHideSubmenu(i.fsttitle, key) : null}>
                                        {icoJson}
                                        <span>{i.fsttitle}{i.sndtitle}{i.trdtitle}</span>
                                </a>
                                {i.menu && renderMenu(i.menu)}
                                {this.state.showfstmenu === i.fsttitle && (
                                    <>{i.fstmenu && renderMenu(i.fstmenu)}</>
                                )}
                                <>{i.sndmenu && renderMenu(i.sndmenu)}</>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            )
        }
        return (
            <nav className="nav">
                <div className="menu">
                    {renderMenu(this.state.navigation.menu)}
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `key` parameter in `map` function.
Then you can pass `index` to `onClick` event handler.

```
class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        ["showHideSubmenu"].forEach((method) => {
            this[method] = this[method].bind(this);
        });

        this.state = {
            navigation: {
                menu: [],
            },
            showSubmenu: -1,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http:json_menuFIN.php')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data =>{
                this.setState({navigation: data});                
            })
    }

    showHideSubmenu(key){
        this.setState({
            showSubmenu: key,
        });
    }
    render(){
        const renderMenu = items => {
            return (
                <ul className="list">
                    {items.map((i, key) => {
                        var icoJson;
                        if(i.ico){
                            icoJson = <Icon icon={i.ico} className={"ico-" + i.ico} />;
                        }
                        var firstMenu = i.fstmenu ? "first-menu" : "";
                        var secondMenu = i.sndmenu ? "second-menu" : "";
                        var classMn = i.fstmenu ? "mn-" : "";
                        var classSb = i.sndmenu ? "sb-" : "";
                        return (
                            <li className={`list__item ${firstMenu}${secondMenu}`} key={i.fsttitle + i.sndtitle + i.trdtitle}>
                                <a 
                                    href={i.URL} 
                                    className={`${classMn}${classSb}`+i.fsttitle}
                                    onClick={(key) => {
                                        if (i.fstmenu) { 
                                            this.showHideSubmenu(key);
                                        }
                                    }
                                >
                                        {icoJson}
                                        <span>{i.fsttitle}{i.sndtitle}{i.trdtitle}</span>
                                </a>
                                {i.menu && renderMenu(i.menu)}
                                {this.state.showSubmenu === key &&
                                    (
                                        <>
                                        {i.fstmenu && renderMenu(i.fstmenu)}
                                        {i.sndmenu && renderMenu(i.sndmenu)}
                                        </>
                                    )
                                }
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            )
        }
        return (
            <nav className="nav">
                <div className="menu">
                    {renderMenu(this.state.navigation.menu)}
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have made your changes in my code and it continues to work as before. When you click on any button ``Parent`` it shows all the sub-menus, not just the one that would be your direct child.

Comment: I had read it but I did not understand you, sorry. I made changes again, but the truth is that I do not know what is wrong, because in my ``console.log (key [0])`` I get 0 1 2, but I do not know how to tell it to only show the key suitable.

Comment: The code not works, I think there is something wrong, sorry for the incovenience

Comment: Right now it does not show any Child when pressing the buttons